# xmlhttp.request fails to open local file

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

The following javascript used to work but now does not.  xmlhttp.status is 0.  The file "SBL_Stats.htm" resides in the same directory as the javascript.

I'm using firefox.

Can anyone help me out?

```
var filePath = "SBL_Stats.htm";

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  Log("Firefox");
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  Log("IE6");
}

xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/plain');  // don't scan for html
xmlhttp.open("GET",filePath,false);  // false means sync request
xmlhttp.send(null);

if (xmlhttp.status != 200)
{ 
  Log("get_SBL_Stats_Data failed: " + xmlhttp.status);
  return "";
}
```

Comment: are you loading an http location or a file?

Comment: All of the files are local.  I.e. they reside in a single directory on my XP system.

Comment: Ok, i see that i get status = 0 for local files :-(  Is there some way for me to determine if files are local or remote?

Comment: if you use sync anyway, why bother to even check the status? you just care about the responseText

Comment: thanks for the help, if you were to post a answer, i'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: i don't expect any pellets for a quip, but i'm glad to have helped...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65239/discussion-between-mike-d-and-dandavis).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dandavis who started me down the right track.  The problem occurs because I was using local files.  I guess that means using the file:: protocol as opposed to the the http:: protocol.  No status is returned when accessing local files.  Removing the status check corrects the problem.  However I wanted to be able to detect if the file could be opened so I added a try catch block around the send call as follows...

```
    try 
    {
      xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      Log("xmlhttp.send error  " + err);
      return "";
    }
```